# Building an orthographic camera for Unity3D, how can I keep four specific targets in sight?

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D Orthographic camera for a game that is built similarly to Tennis. I've been working out the code for this, and I think I'm only part of the way so far. At the moment... it... sort-of keeps the two players in frame, with the frame leading more towards the human player - Player One. However, it also has a tendency to drop below the ground level - especially when it zooms out to keep the targets in view. There are four specific targets: The Ground, Ball, Player One, and Player Two.

The ground should always be at the 'bottom', otherwise when the camera goes below ground it shows sky - not really a desirable effect. This is the code I've developed so far... the two players are effectively paddles, but it only shows the center between them:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    // Moving Camera, This Camera tries to follow Player One, Two, and Ball //

public static CameraController Instance;
public Transform PlayerOne;
public Transform PlayerTwo;
public Transform Ball;

public bool Ready = false;

private float MinX = -46.0f;
private float MaxX = 46.0f;

private float MinY = 12.0f;
private float MaxY = 35.0f;

private float LimitFromPlayerX = 20.0f;
private float LimitFromPlayery = 20.0f;

private float DistanceToGround = 0.0f;
private float DistanceFromCenter = 2.0f;

private float Height = 4.0f;

private float Damping = 5f;

private Vector3 EstimatedCameraPosition = Vector3.zero;
private Vector3 WantedPosition = Vector3.zero;

void Awake()
{
    Instance = this;

}

public void SetCameraPosition()
{
    Vector3 PlayerPosistion = PlayerOne.position;

    PlayerPosistion.z = -10.10f;

    transform.position = PlayerPosistion;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    if (Ready) {
        Vector3 PlayerPosistion = PlayerOne.position;

        PlayerPosistion.z = -10.10f;

        Vector3 CameraPosition = transform.position;

        CameraPosition.z = -10.10f;

        // Get the Distance from the Player to the Ball //
        Vector3 WantedPosition = PlayerTwo.transform.position - -PlayerOne.transform.position;

        float WPMag = Mathf.Abs(WantedPosition.magnitude);

        WPMag = Mathf.Clamp(WPMag, 20, 40);

        Debug.Log(WPMag);

        Camera.main.orthographicSize = WPMag;

        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(CameraPosition, WantedPosition, Damping * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector3 Posit = transform.position;
    Posit.x = Mathf.Clamp (Posit.x, MinX, MaxX);
    Posit.y = Mathf.Clamp (Posit.y, MinY, MaxY);

    transform.position = Posit;
}
```

}

WPMag was my attempt to zoom out and match the players at least, but so far it's only partially working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep all three objects in view, you'll want to focus the camera on the midpoint or "average" position of the three objects. Getting the midpoint of three objects works just like getting the midpoint of two objects: `(PlayerOne.position + PlayerTwo.position + Ball.position) / 3.0f`

You'll then want to set orthographic size to the furthest distance from the midpoint of the three tracked objects. This will ensure that all three objects stay in the frame.

Finally, to keep the camera from showing underground skies, you should enforce a lower limit for the camera's Y position. The orthographic size is half the vertical height of the viewport, so you'd use `CameraPosition.y = Mathf.Max(CameraPosition.y, groundHeight + camera.main.orthographicSize)`

Comment: Thank you! I did indeed get that working as you suggested, but the effect didn't work out as well as I hoped it would.